# How to log the PowerShell commands that were run

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell so this is probably obvious or I am barking up the wrong tree with my approach. But searching on here and Google have not helped me (maybe searching for the wrong terminology?)

I am trying to write a simple PowerShell script (which works/runs no problem). However, I also have a requirement to log the process (the commands run and any output) to a txt file which I am struggling to achieve. I have tried to use the start-transcript and add the `-verbose` common parameter, but it is not working as I would expect.

My end goal is for the script to run on one of our servers which will stop a service, stop any related processes for the service, and then start the service again. But for this example of not being able to log what is happening I have simplified it to just starting and stopping a process. My example is below:

```
Start-Transcript -path "C:\tester.txt" 

Write-Host "starting the shell command"

Start-Process notepad -verbose
Start-Sleep -s 5
Stop-Process -processname notepad -verbose

Stop-Transcript
```

The script runs, Notepad opens, waits for 5 seconds, and then closes again. However, the verbose output is only created for the stop-process command which results in only the write-host message and the stop-process being written to my transaction/logfile. However I need it to write to my file that the Notepad process was started and then stopped.

Comment: What is your PowerShell version? I would expect this to show the commands you run but it does not for me so I am testing.

Comment: Are you running this in ISE? I get similar results to you. It works in actually PowerShell prompt though. So it would be a bug or status quo. Not sure which. Trying running this in regular PowerShell

Comment: @Matt - I have tried running the script from the regular powershell as well but get the same results.

Comment: @Matt - I have the following version. Major - 5, Minor - 1, Build - 14393, Revision 576

Comment: Yes. That happened to me as well. What happens if you run the commands from the shell.... not the script. I copied and pasted your code and it worked. Not an answer but troubleshooting.

Comment: yep, logged everything that time when running it line by line with copy and paste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below script will give you what you are asking for:

I have added comments in the script itself on each phase for better understanding. You can add a *Logfile.txt* check if it exists or not, based on that you can also create the file. *Get-History*  will give you the history of all the commands which have been executed on the shell.

```
$Log_File= "E:\LogFile.txt"

Clear-History
# You can do a file check using Test-Path followed by the path

## Out-file will give the output to the file, -Force will create the file if not existed and -append will append the data.
"starting the shell command" | Out-File $Log_File -Force -Append

Start-Process notepad -verbose

"Notepad started" | Out-File $Log_File -Append

Start-Sleep -s 5
Stop-Process -processname notepad -verbose

"Notepad stopped" | Out-File $Log_File -Force -Append

"List of commands which are executed are below: " | Out-File $Log_File -Force -Append
Get-History | Out-File $Log_File -Append
```

**Sample File OUTPUT:**

**[image: Sample file output is attached as screenshot:]**

**For Remote Execution:**

> Get-Process -Name notepad  -ComputerName SERVER01 | Stop-Process

**Note**: There are multiple ways to stop the service remotely. Go through PowerShell Remoting and see the details.

Comment: So should you just take out transrcript lines for this workaround? Also you might _consider_ clearing the history at the beginning so you don't get stuff that was not executed before this.

Comment: Yes. we can take the transcript lines out. Yes that also is a nice idea to clear the history in the beginning. Let me put that . @Matt

Comment: A safer idea would be just to output `((Get-History).CommandLine)[-1]` to file after each execution. That way you get the order as well as preserving the history

Comment: @Matt:  Done with the modification. Yes we can use that also

Comment: @RanadipDutta- Certainly getting a lot closer. When I run the above script line by line I get the same result, however when I execute the script either within ISE or the powershell prompt I only get the first part of the message logged, with no command history. When I add ((get-history).commandline)[-1] | Out-File $Log_File -Append  after each command I get an error back regarding a NULL array. Does this mean that when run as a script the history is not stored?

Comment: Which PSVersion you are in ? check with "$PSVersiontable"

Comment: PSVersion 5.1.14393.576

Comment: Ah  the reason being. There is no command which has run previously. So use `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1` ....

Comment: Other way to do that is to push the results into an array and then loop through the get-history results outputting the command followed by its output.

Comment: Yeah, I had just managed to find the array loop thingy too. However when I try either option (and combine them) I still do not get any history results back when running as script

Comment: @Jonny_Bravo:  Good then. Just try the set-debug also. ... Accept the answer if it helps you